# Rails App Integration with HPQC (HP Quality Centre)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hp-quality-center

I wanted to integrate hp quality centre to a rails app which is developed and deployed on a linux system.

I found that it uses the OTA (Open Test Architecture API). However it been specified that it uses a OTAclient dll for doing the activities of the api.

I would like to know if there is any documentation of such an integration been done (hpqc+rails on a linux system) ?
Is it possible to attain this integration.. Any gems or plugins...?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the OTAclient.dll requires a number of Windows only dll's. We eventually created a web service on a Windows machine in C# to provide an access point for our Ruby services.

The newer version of HPQC (ALM 11) has a REST-like service that you can use but upgrading to ALM 11 may be a bit much for what you are trying to do.

Comment: So you mean to say there is no alternative for it to work on a linux system other than this..?

Comment: Unfortunately no. OTAClient.dll is a COM object and is tightly bound to the Windows system.

Comment: Also I wanted to know one more thing.. Did you face any issue when multiple communication were been tried between the wrapper(web-service) and hpqc ?

Comment: We were only doing data pulls with that setup as we did not want to encounter any session errors with the, uh, fragile setup we had. So no we did not have any communication issues.